# How do I send a desktop shortcut (to a local html file on THEIR machine) to various users and have it work and retain custom icon?

Tags: file, icons, local, shortcut-file

I created a simple app that is a HTML page that generates price quotes. The client wanted it on certain machines and no where on their intranet. So I have a folder with the html page and a javascript file and custom icon. I want to send them a zip file of this folder with a shortcut file already created with the custom icon (that is inside the folder I'm sending).

1. The link isn't launching the index file in the folder
2. shortcut retains icon and file locations on MY machine.
3. why can't I edit the shortcut target from "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Current Projects\app\desktop\FOLDER\index.html" to just "FOLDER\index.html" ?????
4. SAME THING AS #3 but for the shortcuts START IN

Why can't I just use %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\FOLDER\index.html ???